# Holding onto database connection while using 'yield'

Tags: c#, .net, database-connection, ado, yield

I have a basic data class (stripped back for brevity & that it compiles):

```
public static class Database
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetRecords<T>(string query, Func<IDataReader, T> mappingFunction)
    {
        var connectionString = "";
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection)) 
            {
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)) 
                {
                    while(reader.Read()) {
                        yield return mappingFunction(reader);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var records = Database.GetRecords("SELECT FirstName FROM [Order]", reader => 
                                          new Order { FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString() });

public class Order {
    public string FirstName;
}
```

I have another version that returns a `List<T>` as such:

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)) 
{
    var items = new List<T>();
    while(reader.Read()) {
        items.Add(mappingFunction(reader));
    }
    return items;
}
```

I am adding the `IEnumerable<T>` for some read-only, single iteration part of the application that is used to generate reports. It fetches many rows and needs to perform some mapping to project the database fields onto a model for a report.

When building some of these report models, further queries are needed, so each iteration of the enumerable may call three further database calls. For example, when dealing with an Order, I need to fetch its items - I could do this with a join but that means having to parse/split complex results)

Since the reports are user generated based on several filters available, there could be thousands of items being returned & enumerated. A side effect is now that the database connection is being "held onto" for the duration of this mapping process. Is this a bad approach?

I am generating the reports using the CsvHelper library, which can work with `IEnumerable`, so  I figured that `IEnumerable` from the DB back to client code would reduce memory usage since the enumerable is only being

I understand that `SqlConnections` should be short-lived - so perhaps this delayed deferral of results is an anti-pattern.

I guess here it's the trade off over memory usage vs. SQL connection time

```
var orders = Database.GetRecords("SELECT [things] FROM [Order]", reader =>  MapOrder(reader));

IEnumerable<ReportRecord>() GetRecords(IEnumerable<Order> orders) 
{
    foreach (var order in orders) 
    {
        var reportRecord = new ReportRecord();
        var items = GetOrderItems(order);

        // other queries, calculations etc

        yield return reportRecord;
    }
}

// save to disk using CsvHelper and output file
CsvHelper.Save(GetRecords(), filepath); // fake code -- but uses the IEnumerable instead of materialised list
```

Comment: FYI, you can stack your `using` statements if you want to avoid all that nesting

Comment: cheers, I am actually using VB.NET but am at home so just mocked up the equivalent in C#